# jQuery click event not running on first click. (go to top of page action)

Tags: javascript, jquery

As described in the title, here's the code. It won't work on the first click after refresh of page.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#myBtn').fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('#myBtn').fadeOut();
      }
    });
  });

  function topFunction() {
    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('#myBtn').click(function () {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
      return false;
    });

  }
```

Comment: take the click function outside topfunction

Comment: Add the click handler in `$(document).ready` function.

Comment: Took the click function outside top function, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#myBtn').fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('#myBtn').fadeOut();
      }
    });

    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('#myBtn').click(function () {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
      return false;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this,

- You had not triggered your topFunction on ready.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
topFunction();
    //Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#myBtn').fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('#myBtn').fadeOut();
      }
    });
  });

  function topFunction() {
    //Click event to scroll to top
    $('#myBtn').click(function () {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 200);
      return false;
    });

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>

<p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
<p>

<button id="myBtn" onclick="topFunction"> ScrolTop </button>
test</p>


<p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p><p>test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only had to take out click function outside the other function.